# slice not working as expected

Tags: php

how come?
this works (counts the files in the dir correctly):

```
$result = count($files[0]);
echo $result;
```

and this works  (gets the LAST (newest) file in the dir correctly):

```
$finalone = end($files[0]);
echo $finalone;
```

but this returns the single word "array"

```
$nfive = -5;
$lastfive = array_slice($files[0], $nfive);
echo $lastfive;
```

What I really want to do is **pull the LAST 5 (last NEWEST) files** from that dir.

Dennis

Comment: Because [`array_slice()` returns an array](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php). When echoing an array directly, you get the word `Array` as its string representation.

Comment: `print_r($lastfive)` to see what's in there.  You'll need to loop over it or maybe `implode()` it into a string for output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This portion of the code:

```
$nfive = -5;
$lastfive = array_slice($files[0], $nfive);
echo $lastfive;
```

Should be like this; note the [`print_r`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php):

```
$nfive = -5;
$lastfive = array_slice($files[0], $nfive);
print_r($lastfive);
```

You have split one array into another array. So the `echo` behavior you explained is expected.

Comment: bingo.. that got it. Thank you!

Comment: well, it mostly works.. that is, it works the first time but then the files don't get updated.. 20 minutes later I run it again and it still has the same file list as the first time .. there should be at least three new ones.

Comment: Jake, Yes, of course.. Your solution did answer the question. I'm sure the other problem is cache related and I'll work through that. thanks again.